# Time series classification problem in python

Tags: python, pytorch

My dataset looks like this. How to feed this to a RNN model. Should I be extracting values for each hour for each user as a feature and feed it to the RNN or is there is a way to feed the data directly like the way it is now. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Questions like "what is the best way to..." are fundamentally incorrect in machine learning. We can argue about variance of an estimator or even calculate it if we assume a model with few parameters and a distribution of the data, but optimality can't be argued since we do not know how the data distributed in real life.

Addressing to your question directly, you didn't specify how the data is saved, file type, structure, size, etc. You lack a lot of details that can help us help you. Moreover, there are just a few cases I know that data preparation is not needed, and all of them are international famous datasets (like MNIST and some other old competitions). You need and should prepare your data before feeding it to a network; Moreover, you should experiment different methods (normalize it, etc.) and measure your performance on an holdout set (validation) to see which is better. You can try and separate those by using `torchvision.transforms` even though its is not a vision task. This is a powerful pipeline for preprocessing.

Eventually, you should also experiment with different architectures and units as the time-series deep learning had a significant progression in the last few years (from variational dropout to convolutions and attention units).